# Unable to scrape the Next page URLs using Selenium and scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am struggling to parse/scrape each page after clicking the Next button using Selenium. I am able to go to the second page, however, it fails after that. Not sure how to solve this, any suggestions?
Here is the code:

```
class PropertyFoxSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'property_fox'
    start_urls = [
        'https://propertyfox.co.za/listing-search?currentpage=1&term_id=62515&keywords=Western+Cape&orderby=createddate:desc&status%5B%5D=Active'
    ]


    def __init__(self):
        #path to driver
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('path')


    def parse(self,response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        while True: 
            try: 
                elem = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "pagerNext")))
                elem.click()
                url = self.driver.current_url
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_page, dont_filter=False)
            except TimeoutException:
                break



    def parse_page(self, response):
        #self.driver.get(response.url)
        for prop in response.css('div.property-item'):
            link = prop.css('a::attr(href)').get()
            banner = prop.css('div.property-figure-icon div::text').get()
            sold_tag = None
            if banner:
                banner = banner.strip()
                sold_tag = 'sold' if 'sold' in banner.lower() else None

            yield scrapy.Request(
                link,
                callback=self.parse_property,
                meta={'item': {
                    'agency': self.name,
                    'url': link,
                    'offering': 'buy',
                    'banners': banner,
                    'sold_tag':  sold_tag,
                }},
            )
    def parse_property(self, response):
        item = response.meta.get('item')
     ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait until URL changed and then scrape it

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = self.driver.current_url
elem = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "pagerNext")))
elem.click()
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver: self.driver.current_url != url)
url = self.driver.current_url
```

Comment: Thanks this helps! However, when I run it once it works okay, when I run it again it fails on the second page and the scraper shuts down, and the third time it works again.. any ideas why this might be happening?  @JaSON

Comment: @saraherceg do you mean that you got `TimeOutException` on `WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver: self.driver.current_url != url)` line?

Comment: hm I am not sure if that is the case, cause it works once, and each time I run the scraper it does something different. It either works okay, shuts down after visiting the second page, or somehow ends up on the property link? Those scenarios happen and I am unsure of why.. @JaSON

Comment: @saraherceg try to move this line out of `try/except` block - leave it just for Next button pressing. Then let me know Exception log

Comment: Great, thank you very much, now everything works like a charm! @JaSON

Comment: @saraherceg Great if it works now, but actually I'm not sure that this might solve described issue :) I asked to do this just for debugging purpose. In this way you could know exact Exception

Comment: I am not sure why it doesn't crash or visits a property page anymore, but as soon as I moved that line it now goes to all pages and after visiting all of them I get raise `TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`
but all of the properties from each page are scraped @JaSON

Comment: @saraherceg hmm... I also not sure... I need to see complete code you're currently using. It's better to submit new question with your current code

Comment: Ok posted! Thanks! @JaSON